# #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'username_clean'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Why in my MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phpbb_users_copy` (
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username_clean` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_password` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

when I do a query

```
UPDATE  phpbb_users 
SET     username_clean ='username' AND 
        user_password ='$H$76MZf0m0LJ5T1Tkz/' AND 
        user_email ='2mlrfc4b.wmk@email.com' AND 
        username ='Username' 
WHERE username_clean ='username'
```

I get an error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'username_clean'
```

Comment: Are you sure, your UPDATE is syntactically correct?

Comment: What do you mean by syntactically correct

Comment: @EugenRieck i can't believe the query runs in sqlfiddle. I mean it did not generate a syntax error exception. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49352/1

Comment: I was not sure, if it was a repeated typo in the OQ or ment so ... seems like either sqlfiddle or I have some learning to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when using `UPDATE` statement, you need to separate the columns to be updated by a `COMMA` and not an `AND`

```
UPDATE  phpbb_users 
SET     username_clean ='username' ,
        user_password ='$H$76MZf0m0LJ5T1Tkz/' , 
        user_email ='2mlrfc4b.wmk@email.com' ,
        username ='Username' 
WHERE   username_clean ='username'
```

- [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//update.html)

**UPDATE**

Please take note that you are updating on table `phpbb_users` and not on `phpbb_users_copy`.